# How to expand a control beyond the parent's bounds?

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox

I'm trying to popup a list box when a toggle button is clicked. In the code behind I work with the *Visibility* property and set it to *Visibility.Visible*. However, although the list box appears on the screen, it gets cropped to the size of the toggle box (30x30), instead of, as I wish it to, its own size (99x99).

```
<ToggleButton HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,0"
              VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="30" Height="30"
              Click="ButtonBase_OnClick">
  <ListBox x:Name="listBox1"
           ClipToBounds="False" 
           Visibility="Collapsed"
           HorizontalAlignment="Left"
           Height="99" 
           VerticalAlignment="Top" 
           Width="99">
    <CheckBox x:Name="checkBox3" Content="CheckBox"/>
    <CheckBox x:Name="checkBox4" Content="CheckBox"/>
  </ListBox>
</ToggleButton>
```

I've tried setting the property *ClipToBounds* to *false* but it didn't give much change. I also tried setting the height of the combo box to *Auto*. That made a scroll bar appear (a horizontal one, though, which itself was a bit unexpected) but everything was still cropped to the toggle box's bounds.

What do I need to set more? Or am I approaching it the wrong way (as in: should I define the combo box inside the toggle button's child tags for templates, trigger and what not)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want the listbox *inside* the toggle button, you should not place it inside the toggle button. Place it outside of the toggle button and it should work. Maybe you should have a look at the `Expander` control, that seems to do what you need. It will still not make the expanders body larger than the expander.

Something else to note: it's bad style to set fixed sizes. Try to partition your window using the containers like Grid and the various Panels and you will not need fixed sizes. If your toggle button does not have a fixed size, it could expand when the contents need expansion.

Comment: As for the sizes - agreed. In this particular case, the toggler **must** be a certain size, though. As for the *Expander* - I tried adding something called *Popup*. Is that what you mean?

Comment: I meant an [Expander](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.controls.expander%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), something that you can expand when you need to see more.

Comment: Ah, you might just given me a different approach all together. I'll have a bunch of checkboxes in there (the number of which is dynamically determined from a property serving an array, so I'll have to customize the contents of it to something else than a grid, but still...

Comment: A listbox seems fine if you have an IEnumerable (for example an array) of stuff to display or bind to. If you really want your fixed size button and listbox you could put them both into a grid with the button in the first row and the list in the second.

Comment: Naa, only the device unfolding the list needs to be a certain size. A button could expand if the text on it changes. The expander has its text outside of the visual thingy, so the problem become moot. Really good suggestion, mate. +1